# How do I get the ResultCode from Exec call on Batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, inno-setup

I have the following line of code in my script, which instead of calling the exe directly, invokes a batch file.

```
Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\App\bin\migrate.bat'), '', '', sw_show, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

And the batch file looks something like this (top stuff is mostly for debugging purposes but might contain some sort of user interaction later).

```
echo %path%
echo %cd%
migrate.exe Obfuscate.dll /verbose /startupConfigurationFile="..\Web.config
pause
```

Should I wish to get the return code from migrate.exe and return it as a ResultCode, like you normally would get from directly calling the exe, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with Inno-Setup and how it handles this situation, but from the side of the batch script you would typically do something like this (tailored for your specific example):

```
echo %path%
echo %cd%
migrate.exe Obfuscate.dll /verbose /startupConfigurationFile="..\Web.config
set rc=%ERRORLEVEL%
pause
exit /b %rc%
```

Of course assuming that `migrate.exe` returns 0 on success and non-zero otherwise and that Inno-Setup's Exec call interprets such return values as "true" and "false" respectively (chances are good it does because that is "standard", but YMMV).

Comment: @aschipfl I was playing it safe. I don't know if `pause` changes the error level.

Comment: @aschipfl In this specific case yes, but the way the answer shows is more safe, should the OP decide to add other commands before the `exit`.

Comment: @Christian.K, `pause` does not change the `ErrorLevel`; but @MartinPrikryl is right, using variable `rc` makes it more safe and general...